# IPTABLES - Bad IP Address

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I am trying to turn my Raspberry Pi into a VPN server. To do this I am following [this tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing).

The only issue is when it tells to to run this command `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.XX.X`. The tutorial tells me that `10.8.0.0` is the default IP address of my Raspberry Pi (which I'm guessing is `192.168.1.0` for me), however I do not know what the `192.168.XX.X` is meant to be.

When I try and run `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.XX.X`, I end up getting this error:

```
iptables v1.4.14: Bad IP address "192.168.XX.X"

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

What do I need to put for 192.168.XX.X?

Here is the output of `ifconfig | grep eth0 -A6`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ff:77:60  
          inet addr:192.168.1.64  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:81551 errors:0 dropped:15591 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7561855 (7.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1154863 (1.1 MiB)
```

and `route -F` give

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         BThomehub.home  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         BThomehub.home  0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

The question is what do I replace `192.168.XX.X` with in the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.XX.X` command?

Comment: If you literally tried to use `192.168.XX.X` as an parameter to `ìptables`, no wonder it complains (IP addresses can't contain letters). The IP at the end of the command should be the IP of the network interface connected to the Internet, and the first IP (or actually, a network) would be the one the VPN clients will be having.

Comment: @zagrimsan So do you mean `192.168.XX.X` would be the gateway then? In my case this would be `192.168.1.254` (router IP)? When doing the command I wasn't sure if `X` was meaning wild card. I have never used iptables before.

Comment: That being said, I think you need to first do some reading on NAT (and maybe also IP networking in general) or you won't be able to troubleshoot any issues that might (or in my experience, will) occur before you've set up openvpn successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial you cited](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing) doesn't say what you think it says.

> Don’t forget to change the default IP address to your Pi’s IP address!
>
> Let’s break this down: 10.8.0.0 is the default address for Raspberry Pi for > clients that are connected to the VPN.

So, the `10.8.0.0` is the subnet address from which you will be offering your clients an IP address (this is a `/24` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`) according to [this configuration file](https://gist.github.com/laurenorsini/9925434) referenced from your tutorial, and `192.168.X.X` is your local address, i.e. `192.168.1.64` in your instance.

Comment: Ok. Do you mean that I need to do `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.0` or is it `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.64`? if so where does the '10.8.0.0' come from?

Comment: @iProgram,like I said in my Answer, the `10.8.0.0` is defined in the configuration file that was referenced as part of the tutorial. If you're using a different configuration file please update your Question to include it.

Comment: When I tried my client ovpn configuration files (different to the one you are talking about) it failed anyway. Using a pre made free VPN server. Using it so I can use SSL when it is not available on open networks.

Comment: @iProgram have you made the appropriate changes to the server config which is linked in the tutorial? I mean those lines with trailing comments reminding to change the value to what is correct for your setup. It also seems to attempt to provide LAN access together with internet access, something which I myself didn't manage to do (however, I didn't use that tutorial). Anyway, it might be that some parts are working while some aren't, and so "it failed" is not enough info. You should start with pinging the server and devices in the LAN, your DNS server and checking if DNS works.